# Information not displaying in Playa field

Tags: playa, pixelandtonic, fieldtype

I'm unable to get any relationship information to display within my Playa field. I'm using ExpressionEngine 2.5.2 with Playa 4.0.5 installed and my license key input. I have an information selected within my channel entry in the Playa field.

My playa field is titled "testplaya2" and here is the code that I'm using to display the playa information:

```
 {exp:channel:entries  channel="tours" limit="1" url_title="{segment_2}" status="open|hidden" show_future_entries="yes" show_expired="yes"}
 <div class="section">
    {testplaya2}
        {title}
    {/testplaya2}
 </div>
 {/exp:channel:entries}
```

Am I missing something?

Comment: Please post a more complete code sample... what's surrounding this code? Is it inside a channel:entries tag?

Comment: Hi @Anna_MediaGirl, I just added more complete code. Yes, it is in a channel entries tag - details above.

Comment: Is {title} printing out the title of the main entry instead of the Playa entries?

Comment: {title} was actually showing nothing at all, but it was because the entry had expired. @diemer's answer below was the fix. thanks for the help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is the entry that you've selected in the Playa field expired? Playa defaults to no for show_future_entries and show_expired.

Comment: hi @diemer, that was it! I just added statements to my playa field to fix it: {testplaya2 show_future_entries="yes" show_expired="yes"}{title}{/testplaya2}